# trying to combine two scripts together with a check box and toggle

Tags: jquery, checkbox, toggle, unchecked

I have a link when clicked by the user  will ***uncheck*** a checkbox.

When the checkbox is unchecked, I want a div to be hidden.  Only when the checkbox is checked the div is displayed.

Both scripts work independently, but together they do not.  When I refresh the page, the link to uncheck the checkbox works correctly but the div is displayed.

I need help to combine these two scripts together to ensure the div is displayed when the checkbox is checked AND the checkbox is unchecked by a link.

HTML:

```
<a id="uncheck-all" href="#sharestory2" class="share_cont1">Continue</a>

<input  type="checkbox" name="agreeCheckbox" value="Accept" onchange="toggleLink(this);">

<div class="share_cont_PRO"  id="agreeLink" style="display:none;"><a href="#sharestory3" class="share_contPRO">Proceed To Sharing</a></div>
```

SCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#uncheck-all').click(function(){
$("input:checkbox").attr('checked', false);
  });
});   



function toggleLink(checkBox)
 {
var link = document.getElementById("agreeLink");

if (checkBox.checked)
    link.style.display = "inline";
else
    link.style.display = "none";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you can just trigger the change event of the checkbox inside the event handler for the click:

```
$('#uncheck-all').click(function () {
    $("input:checkbox").attr('checked', false);
    $(this).next('input[type="checkbox"]').trigger('change');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nvnhaLbr/